# how to get from hotmail the "X-message-delivrey" and "IP" using imap and php?

Tags: php, outlook, imap, hotmail

i want to extract  the **x-message-delivery** and **ip** from outlook ,and i tried the normal library of IMAP ,but there's no specefic tag to search for it.
i'm using php in laravel, and i want to fetch those informations and i already connect my imap to *HOTMAIL* .

```
 $regExp = '/^(((?=(?>.*?(::))(?!.+\3)))\3?|([\dA-F]{1,4}(\3|:(?!$)|$)|\2))(?4){5}((?4){2}|((2[0-4]|1\d|[1-9])?\d|25[0-5])(\.(?7)){3})\z/i';
            $header = explode("\n", imap_fetchheader($conn, 1));
            echo implode("\n",$header);
          preg_match_all($regExp,implode("\n",$header),$array );
         print_r($array);
```

this what i tried for ip bur it print empty array
and this id the result

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) [2] => Array ( ) [3] => Array ( ) )
```

Comment: What have you tried?  If you're trying to extract this information, you just download the headers for the message, parse them, and inspect them.  The last hop IP before your server is in the top-most Received header.  Any Received header after that can't be trusted.

Comment: yes that what i tried but no seem to work

Comment: And do you see them all in your $header variable?    Do you see anything that looks like an IP?  Did you write that regexp?

Comment: no i just copy it yes i see all the information in my $header  variable i think the problem is with that regexp